# Sending out multiple reports as one email in splunk

Tags: reporting, splunk, splunk-query

I have 2 different independent queries and I want to send out a single email having these 2 reports as PDFs. Is there a way to achieve this in splunk.

Edit- Tried putting the reports to a dashboard and then scheduling a pdf delivery but I don't see that option. It seems like it requires some extra permissions which won't be possible for me to get :([image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is - put both reports into a Dashboard, and schedule the Dashboard to be delivered every morning at 8a (or whenever you like).

### Adding a Report to a Dashboard as a Panel is pretty straightforward*:

[image: dashboard 1]

[image: dashboard 2]

[image: dashboard 3]

[image: dashboard 4]

### Add as many panels as you desire to the dashboard, then schedule it:

[image: schedule 1]

[image: schedule 2]

---

***Note***: you *do* have to have appropriate permissions to schedule Reports, Dashboards, Alerts, etc - so make sure you have them in place

---

<sup>* <sub>all screenshots taken with an admin account - your view may look different based on your assigned role(s)</sub></sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying but I don't see the option to schedule PDF delivery. The only two options that i see are export PDF and print.

Comment: @Kunalgupta - then either your user likely doesn't have permission to schedule delivery. Can anyone else schedule delivery?

Comment: None, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kunalgupta - not even the *admins*?

Comment: That's a long list of access policies to go through. I was hoping for workarounds but doesn't seem like there are any xD

Comment: @Kunalgupta - no, there's not *supposed* to be "workarounds" for RBAC :)

Comment: I meant workarounds for having multiple searches trigger one report xD

Comment: @Kunalgupta ... if you can't schedule a *Dashboard* via email delivery ... you won't be able to schedule a *Report*, either :) ..really need to talk to whomever in your org authorizes this stuff and get your perms updated to  be able to do what you're asking for - or get someone else to take your Reports/Dashboards and get them scheduled

Comment: Apparently I was able to schedule reports but not dashboards. I had power user access. Talked to one of the admins. They scheduled the delivery and handed over the job to me which i can then schedule like I want. Thanks for the engagement man! Appreciate it.

Comment: @Kunalgupta - glad I was able to help! (added a note about perms in the answer)